# What happens to files that are not moved on uploading?

Tags: php, apache

When a file is uploaded using an HTML page to the server (I'm using PHP as backend scripting language and Apache web server ) using POST method, the programmer is supposed to move the uploaded file from its temporary location to some other location using [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). However, if due to some reason the file is not moved, what happens to the uploaded file? Does it remain there forever, or is the file deleted as soon as the script exits ?

Comment: I have seen a windows server were the temporary directory was filled to the size limit with uploaded files, blocking any further uploads. So I think it would depend on the OS and the location of the temporary directory used by PHP.

Comment: First action should always be to [check the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) instead of ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From  PHP DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

It does not really matter if it is moved or not

Comment: Guess what .. i edited yours instead of mine :)

Comment: @Baba Umm, you literally completely changed my answer.  Did you mean to edit your own post and edited mine instead?

Comment: I can revert if you want @Crontab

Comment: @Crontab you should thank him. He added an actual source to  an answer that had none :)

Comment: No worries, @Baba.  And I suppose I could've sourced the fact that I just got done with a file upload script not more than 15 minutes ago that answered this exact question.  =)